# Remember Selectbox value after form submitted with error

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

Right now if i submit my form and there is an error it just shows there is an error, without reselecting the project there was an error for, (the page is called "change project") here u can change the values for a certain project.

P.S. in the picture i posted u can see i specifically entered a string 'test' where there should be an integer.

I tried  $("#categorieSelect").val($_POST['categorieSelect']); but it didn't work

```
<div id="project-wijzigen" class="form">
        <h2> Wijzig een project </h2>       
 <?php
            echo form_open('c_admin/project'); //moet ge nog aanpassen
            echo '<select id="categorieSelect" name="categorieSelect"></select>';
            echo form_input('startdatum', set_value('startdatum'), 'placeholder="Startdatum"');
            echo form_input('einddatum', set_value('einddatum'), 'placeholder="Einddatum"');
            echo form_input('projecttitel', set_value('projecttitel'), 'placeholder="Projecttitel"');
            echo form_input('ism', set_value('ism'), 'placeholder="In samenwerking met"');
            echo form_input('projecttekst', set_value('projecttekst'), 'placeholder="Projecttekst"');
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Project wijzigen');
            echo form_close();

// --------------------------- Error checking/display           
            if(isset($projectWijzigenError)) // check of de variabele wel een waarde heeft (als je die zomaar oproept en hij moest leeg of NULL zijn dan krijg je een error op je pagina)
                {
                if ($projectWijzigenError=='true') // ALS er een error is, dan opent de form terug en worden errors weergegeven
                {
                $("#categorieSelect").val($_POST['categorieSelect']);
                alert($_POST['categorieSelect']);
?>
                    <script>
                    alert($_POST['categorieSelect']);
                    $('#project-wijzigen').show();
                    $(this).toggleClass('close');
                    </script>

<?php 
                echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); 
                }  
                }
// -------------------------- End error checking/displaying             
?>

    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: How about client side validation as well?

Comment: What do you mean ? I'm pretty noob to all this :x

Answer (score 2):

You are "mixing" the server side with the client side. When you use javascript you're programming on the client side and you can´t access variables in the server. So php code will not work on javascript.
In

```
<script> alert($_POST['categorieSelect']);
         $('#project-wijzigen').show(); 
         $(this).toggleClass('close'); 
</script>
```

you can´t access $_POST which is a server variable.

You shoud make something  like this:

```
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" id="hidden-input" value="'.$_POST['categorieSelect'].'">'; ?>
```

and then, in your script:

```
<script> alert($('#hidden-input').val());
         $('#project-wijzigen').show(); 
         $(this).toggleClass('close'); 
</script>
```

Comment: $("#categorieSelect").val($('#hidden-input').val()); isn't doing anything

Comment: if you're replacing the line  $("#categorieSelect").val($_POST['categorieSelect']); by  $("#categorieSelect").val($('#hidden-input').val()); in your code  it will not work.
You're are mixing client side programming with server side in this lines

 if(isset($projectWijzigenError)){ if ($projectWijzigenError=='true'){$("#categorieSelect").val($_POST['categorieSelect']); alert($_POST['categorieSelect']); ...... this will never work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeigniter validation.